# How do I drop all real files after checking them out from DVC, keeping only the stubs?

Tags: dvc

DVC, or data version control, allows me to stub out large files with an MD5 hash, push them to a remote store, and version control the hash.

Then, I can checkout those files from the remote and have them locally.

---

However, sometimes those files are big and my preference when managing many repos with large files is to only have large files checked out in the project I am working on now.  Otherwise, I would like to have my local disk storage freed up with the large files only in the cloud, or only on my local machine in compressed form if they must (ideally no: the files may already be compressed, and additional compression will not shrink them).

I have existing scripts that do this manually, although it is complicated to "clean up" correctly in all cases, and I'd like to forget about them.

What is the DVC procedure or command to "clean up" all checked out content or otherwise remotely controlled data s.t. none exists locally (and disk space is freed) but all `*.dvc` files are retained?

Comment: You can try this to clean up all local data that's been pushed to cloud: https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/gc#--not-in-remote?

Comment: @davemb83 hey thanks for that tip, it will definitely simplify one half of this: cleaning up dvc's cached data.

Comment: @Chris could you clarify a bit, what else do you have in mind that is not handled by `gc` for you? I reading the question, and I'm not 100% I understand it tbh.

Comment: @Shcheklein I'd like the actual files that are stubbed out by DVC and which are version controlled with the known md5 to be destroyed in order to free up disk space after they've been downloaded and checked out of a remote.  This probably isn't trivial, since DVC has to know that the file in question was pulled from a remote location and does not yet need to be pushed.

Comment: @Shcheklein another way to frame this function would be to sync and commit all data, push all of it to the remote, and as each item is confirmed to exist on the remote, delete all instances of it on the local machine, including in the cache and the actual file checked out and visible in a directory in the repo.

Comment: @Shcheklein my use case here is in the space of device development. We have many large binaries per project, and many of the devs are managing multiple VMs on older laptops (you know, legacy company laptops) with smaller hard drives (mine is only 512Gb -- with multiple Windows and linux vm drives), so space is really at a premium for many of the guys (myself included).

Comment: @Shcheklein if we can use DVC as sort of a sparse filesystem that allows us to always have clean repos for the purpose of building and testing on our VMs, that will reduce error and improve our workflow when we go to build, test, QA and otherwise validate the binaries are going to work on various IoT OS's we support.

Comment: @Shcheklein otherwise, I've written a script -- but if I can delete or simplify it by using a DVC command, that would be great!